# Installed Kodi on ubuntu 14.04. Kodi will not open

Tags: software-installation

I have ubuntu 14.4 on my pc with no other os on my pc. I downloaded kodi but it will not open.
Hope somebody can help.

Comment: What is your source for download? In your you have written that you have downloaded kodi but you have not written anything about installing it. Please be specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded from Kodi.tv (linux guide icon)
Put this into the terminal as told on the web page,

sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi

The kodi icon appears in Applications, and also in ubuntu software centre. When I click the kodi icon to open kodi, the monitor screen goes black and returns to the desktop without opening kodi.